# dataclass set new value after declaring one

Tags: class, python-dataclasses

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class User:
    name : str
    balance : int
    checking_account : bool

    def withdraw(self,amount):
        if amount > self.balance:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            self.balance -= amount
        return self.name + " " + "has" + " " + repr(self.balance) + "."

    def check(self,other,money):
        if other.checking_account is False:
            raise ValueError
        if other.balance < money:
            raise ValueError
        self.balance += money
        other.balance -= money
        return self.name + " " + "has" + " " + repr(self.balance) + " " + "and" + " " + other.name + " " + "has" + " " + repr(other.balance) + "."

    def add_cash(self,amount):
        self.balance += int(amount)
        return self.name + " " + "has" + " " + repr(self.balance) + "."


Jeff = User("Jeff",70,True)
Joe = User('Joe', 70, False)
print(Jeff.withdraw(2))
#print(Joe.check(Jeff, 50))
#print(Jeff.check(Joe, 80)) # Raises a ValueError
Joe.checking_account = True
print(Jeff.check(Joe, 80)) # Returns 'Jeff has 98 and Joe has 40'
```

I tried to implement a little banking class. As I was doing my tests down below I noticed I couldn't change the boolean value. The variables arent private so why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can change the value of the boolean and you are doing that, your code is raising a value error because of the other conditional inside check method:

```
 if other.balance < money:
        raise ValueError
```

In the test, Jeff has 70 in his balance and you are trying to get 80 as the money parameter specifies, as 70 is lesser than 80 it raises the Value Error.

If you don't have debugging tools, I recommend you to print the variables in different states whenever you are confused on the final output of the program.

You can verify that the boolean has changed to True by printing its value right before the error.

Comment: ah yes thanks I see if I didnt comment the other statements I would have gotten the right output

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it has helped you